# How to recompile dpkg from the source code on debian 10?

Tags: debian

How to recompile dpkg from the source code on debian 10? https://github.com/davidben/dpkg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have you tried using the same runes as with any software, that is `./configure && make && make install`?

in the case of the github repository mentioned there are two things to note:

- The repository does not contain a `configure` script, as this is generated from `configure.ac`: you must run `autoreconf -fiv` as the very first step.
- Since the repository at hand contains the Debian packaging, you can simply re-create the Debian package of `dpkg` using:

  ```
  dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
  ```
- The last commit of the repository was 11 years ago. The version found there is  `dpkg 1.15.4`.
  Current Debian/stable (buster) ships with `dpkg 1.19.7`. Why do you want to re-compile such an outdated version of the software?
- The repository you linked to is just some random repository containing parts of the `dpkg`history. It's not the official repository **at all** (sidenote: i would be amazed to see such a core component of Debian to be hosted on github by upstream!).
  If you want the proper repository, check out

  https://git.dpkg.org/cgit/dpkg/dpkg.git